# Prove that the set $\beta$ = {$O(K,U)$ | $K \subset X$ is compact, $U \subset Y$ is open} is a basis.(Use Munkres' definition)

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$,$Y$ be topological spaces and $C(X,Y)$ be the set of continuous maps $X \rightarrow Y$. If $K \subset X$ and $U \subset Y$, define $O(K,U)$ to be the set of $f \in C(X,Y)$ such that $f(K) \subseteq U$.

Prove that the set $$\beta = \{O(K,U) \mid K \subseteq X \text{ is compact }, U \subseteq Y \text{ is open}\}$$ is a basis for a topology on $C(X,Y)$. (Use Munkres' definition)

My idea:To show the intersection is not empty,I find $f \in O_3 \subseteq O_1 \cap O_2$. Since it doesn't mention that $X$ is Hausdorff,then $K_3 = K_1 \cap K_2$ is not necessarily compact,so I think it should be $K_1 \cup K_2$. But how to deal with $U_3$? Would $U_1 \cup U_2$ work?

Comment: what's the topology on $C(X,Y)$?

Comment: That looks like the standard *subbasis* of the compact-open topology. Why do you think it is a basis?

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown The problem given says it's a basis.

Comment: @XYC I **don't** think it's necessarily a basis.

Comment: @ Lord Shark the Unknown  It's a basis as well as a subbasis

Comment: @XYC what's the standard topology

Comment: I think this is a compact-open topology.But the problem is to show that this subbasis happens to be a basis.

Comment: @mathworker21 He's asked to show that $\beta$ generates a topology on $C(X,Y)$. The set doesn't have a topology yet, that's the whole point.

Comment: $O_1 \cap O_2$ can be empty when $K_1, K_2$ are disjoint.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think $\beta$ is necessarily a base for a topology. It's the standard *subbase* for the so-called compact-open topology on $C(X,Y)$.

A trivial counterexample:

$X=\{0,1\}$ in the discrete topology, $Y=\{0,1\}$ also in the discrete topology, so $C(X,Y)=Y^X$ and $B_1= O(\{0\}, \{0\})\in \beta$ and also
$B_2=O(\{1\},\{1\}) \in \beta$ and $\{f\} = B_1 \cap B_2$ where $f=\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$. But there is no compact $K$ and open $O$ such that $O(K,O)=\{f\}$, as can easily be checked.

Comment: Could you explain what is {(0,0),(1,1)} for f ?

Comment: What does it mean for f={(0,0),(1,1)} ?

Comment: @XYC $f$ is that function. It sends $0$ to $0$ and $1$ to $1$, i.e. the identity. A function is a set of pairs (a special type of relation, so $f:X \to Y$ is a subset of $X \times Y$ etc.)